# Save user Id using Intent in android

Tags: android-intent, android-sqlite

I am beginnerin android developer. Created login page with registration link. When I login to my app I get add baby form. I want to save user id in the add baby form. I colud get email address but unable to get user Id How can I get this?

I am using intent object for this. User id is a primary key for user table. And I want to store it as foreign key in baby table.

```
LoginActivity.java

  String str = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("message", str);

 startActivity(intent);


MainActivity.java

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String str = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    text.setText(str);
```

saving email address instead I want to save user Id but it is on registration page.

Comment: need more information for registration page since you are having problem there.

Comment: Registration code  as a sample
  private void initViews() {
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
        textInputLayoutEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutEmail);
        textInputLayoutPassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutPassword);
      findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutUserName);
        buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

    }

Comment: I am unable to add registration code here

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would get the id when logging in.

For example assuming a table for the user(s) has columns id, email and password.

Then to login you could have a method such as :-

```
public long getUser(String email, String password) {
    long rv = -1;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor csr = db.query(
            TBL_USER,
            null,
            COL_USER_EMAIL + "=? AND " + COL_USER_PASSWORD + "=?",
            new String[]{email,password},
            null,null,null);
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        rv = csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_USER_ID));
    }
    csr.close();
    return rv;
}
```

In the login activity you could then have :-

```
private void login() {
    long userid = mDBHlpr.getUser(mEmail.getText().toString(),mPassword.getText().toString());
    if (userid < 1) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Loging failed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(INTENTKEY_USERDID,userid);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

- mDBHlpr being an instance of the database helper.
- mEmail being the EditText for inputting the email.
- mPassword being the EditText for inputting the password.
- INTENTKEY_USERID being a key (string) used to identify the id value.

MainActivity could then obtain the userid using :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper mDBHlpr;
    long mUserId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mUserId = this.getIntent().getLongExtra(LoginActivity.INTENTKEY_USERDID,-1);
        if (mUserId > 0) {
            Log.d("LOGINSTATUS","Successfully logged in with userid " + String.valueOf(mUserId));
        } else {
            Log.d("LOGINSTATUS","NOT LOGGED IN");
        }
    }
}
```

- Note this assumes that LoginActivity is called before MainActivity and is the initial Activity.

  - If MainActivity were to be the initial activity and call LoginActivity then the methodology would be similar other than you would start LoginActivity using startActivityForResult and use an intent and the setResult in the LoginActivivty along with MainActivity overriding the onActivityResult method. See [Getting a Result from an Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)

Comment: I updated code as per your solution but when I logged in it is not showing main activity page it stuck on login page. anything wrong I am doing here? If you want I can share my .java files.